Android not prompting for Serial USB comms permission or not registering the answer
I am creating a simple android app that connects to an arduino that has a weight sensor. On android 11 this works but I am testing on android 14 and it is either:
Not prompting for the USB permission and denying it automatically
or Prompting for it and even if I say yes, it still denies it.
I am not new to programming but definitely new to Kotling and had long time without coding.
Here is what I have done:

I am sure the device I am running the app on is OTG compatible
I am sure that the device can communicate with the arduino, I used the "Serial USB Terminal" app and can connect and communicate with the arduino from the device and get the weight on the sensor and all of that, so communication is possible.
2.1. That app requests the same permission I need, but probably handles it correctly, unlike me

Here is the class that handles the usb comms.
```class IOPesa(private val context: Context) {
    private var serialPort: UsbSerialDevice? = null
    private var responseData: String? = null
    private val usbManager: UsbManager = context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager
    private val responseLatch = CountDownLatch(1)

    companion object {
        private const val ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.example.testapp.USB_PERMISSION"
        private const val TAG = "IOPesa"
    }

    private val usbPermissionReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION == intent.action) {
                    val device: UsbDevice? = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                    Log.d(TAG, "Broadcast received. Device: $device")
                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false) && device != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Permission granted for device: ${device.deviceName}")
                        connectToDevice(device)
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Permission denied for the device ${device?.deviceName}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        val filter = IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)
        context.registerReceiver(usbPermissionReceiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED)
        discoverDeviceAndRequestPermission()
    }

    private fun discoverDeviceAndRequestPermission() {
        val deviceList = usbManager.deviceList
        val device = deviceList.values.firstOrNull()
        if (device != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Device found: ${device.deviceName}, requesting permission...")
            requestPermission(device)
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "No USB devices connected.")
        }
    }

    private fun requestPermission(device: UsbDevice) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Requesting permission for device: ${device.deviceName}")
        val permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        usbManager.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent)
        Log.d(TAG, "Permission intent sent. Device: $device, PermissionIntent: $permissionIntent")
    }

    private fun connectToDevice(device: UsbDevice) {
        val connection = usbManager.openDevice(device)
        serialPort = UsbSerialDevice.createUsbSerialDevice(device, connection)
        if (serialPort != null && serialPort!!.open()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Connection opened, configuring serial port...")
            configureSerialConnection()
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not open the device connection or create serial device.")
        }
    }

    private fun configureSerialConnection() {
        serialPort?.apply {
            setBaudRate(9600)
            setDataBits(UsbSerialInterface.DATA_BITS_8)
            setStopBits(UsbSerialInterface.STOP_BITS_1)
            setParity(UsbSerialInterface.PARITY_NONE)
            setFlowControl(UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_OFF)
            read { data ->
                responseData = String(data)
                Log.d(TAG, "Received data: $responseData")
                responseLatch.countDown()
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Serial port configured.")
    }

    fun enviar(message: String): String {
        Log.d(TAG, "Sending message: $message")

        responseData = null  // Resetear los datos antes de enviar
        responseLatch.await(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)  // Restablecer el latch

        serialPort?.write(message.toByteArray())

        responseLatch.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)  // Esperar hasta 2 segundos para la respuesta

        return responseData ?: "No response received"
    }

    fun disconnect() {
        serialPort?.close()
        context.unregisterReceiver(usbPermissionReceiver)
        Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected and receiver unregistered.")
    }
}```

here is my manifest:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.testapp">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_HOST" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TestApp"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>```

And here are the logcat outputs I marked "confusing"

**Device found:**
2024-06-22 23:49:05.360 30020-30020 IOPesa                  com.example.testapp                  D  Device found: /dev/bus/usb/001/002, requesting permission...

**Requesting permision**
2024-06-22 23:49:05.360 30020-30020 IOPesa                  com.example.testapp                  D  Requesting permission for device: /dev/bus/usb/001/002

**Request sent**
2024-06-22 23:49:05.377 30020-30020 IOPesa                  com.example.testapp                  D  Permission intent sent. Device: UsbDevice[mName=/dev/bus/usb/001/002,mVendorId=6790,mProductId=29987,mClass=255,mSubclass=0,mProtocol=0,mManufacturerName=null,mProductName=USB Serial,mVersion=2.64,mSerialNumberReader=android.hardware.usb.IUsbSerialReader$Stub$Proxy@7e3e8bc, mHasAudioPlayback=false, mHasAudioCapture=false, mHasMidi=false, mHasVideoCapture=false, mHasVideoPlayback=false, mConfigurations=[
                                                                                                    UsbConfiguration[mId=1,mName=null,mAttributes=128,mMaxPower=49,mInterfaces=[
                                                                                                    UsbInterface[mId=0,mAlternateSetting=0,mName=null,mClass=255,mSubclass=1,mProtocol=2,mEndpoints=[
                                                                                                    UsbEndpoint[mAddress=130,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=32,mInterval=0]
                                                                                                    UsbEndpoint[mAddress=2,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=32,mInterval=0]
                                                                                                    UsbEndpoint[mAddress=129,mAttributes=3,mMaxPacketSize=8,mInterval=1]]]], PermissionIntent: PendingIntent{a5b9045: android.os.BinderProxy@94fa39a}

**Permission Denied** Weather it prompts for it and I say yes or not prompt for it, that is the response I get.

2024-06-22 23:49:07.736 30020-30020 IOPesa                  com.example.testapp                  E  Permission denied for the device null

